# Encrypt a RSA private key and write it to a file using Crypto++

Tags: c++, windows, encryption, crypto++

I'm trying to export a RSA private key to a file, after encrypting it using RSA.
So far, I tried to export it with 2 methods :

```
int main()
{
    AutoSeededRandomPool rnd;
    const std::string publickey_str = 
    "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\n"
    "rsa public key there\n"
    "-----END PUBLIC KEY-----";

    RSA::PublicKey master_publicKey;

    StringSource source(publickey_str, true);
    PEM_Load(source, master_publicKey);

    CryptoPP::RSAES_OAEP_SHA_Encryptor e(master_publicKey);

    InvertibleRSAFunction params;
    params.GenerateRandomWithKeySize(rnd, 4096);

    RSA::PrivateKey privateKey(params);

    FileSink file("exported.bin")

    //Method 1

    FileSink file("exported.bin")
    ArraySource export_private_key(privateKey, sizeof(privateKey),true, AuthenticatedEncryptionFilter(e, new Redirector(file))); //can't find a way to convert privateKey to a valid type for ArraySource

    //Method 2
    privateKey.Save( new AuthenticatedEncryptionFilter(e, new Redirector(file))); //doesn't work, as Save() expects BufferedTransformation
```

Is there any way to achieve my goal using one of these 2 methods, or do I have to convert my private key to another format (BER or PEM encoding) before applying RSA on it ?

Thanks in advance

P.S: My question is Windows specific, if it matters in any way.

Comment: Download the [PEM Pack](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/PEM_Pack) and use it to password protect the private key on-disk. Also (if I am parsing things correctly)... if you encrypt the private key with its public key, then you probably won't be able to use the key to decrypt itself because the private key won't be available at time of decryption.

Answer (score 0):

No.

RSA can only securely encrypt a (much) smaller amount of data than the key size because of the secure padding that is required - in this case OAEP. RSA, like any cipher, encrypts *bytes*, so changing the key to text certainly won't help. It will also further inflate the key size that needs to be encrypted.

What you can do is to use hybrid encryption: first encrypt with AES in a secure mode of operation with a new random key, then encrypt the AES key using RSA.

---

You may want to think about your security scheme; the RSA encryption is only useful if the RSA decryption key is kept *more secure* than the RSA key that you are encrypting. Otherwise you've just shifted the problem to the RSA key pair that *wraps and unwraps* the private key.

Answer (score 0):

There is a YES with some constraints. In the easiest case you try to encrypt a binary BER string of some private RSA key using a 2nd RSA system. The required key size of the 2nd system is somewhat larger, for the BER string has an overhead of may be 100% and also RSA/OAEP entertains some padding tags of about 42 bytes size. So you would form the BER string and generate a RSA Key Pair with (BER size +42) * 8 bits key length.